# MYSQL Query with percentage and other restrictions

Tags: mysql

Hello I am new to MySQL and am in school right now trying to figure out a question that my instructor has asked.  Here is the question:

```
Select ID, name, Country and Population from City Table, Select Life Expectancy, Name, SurfaceArea and GNP from the Country Table.
```

Restrict the result set using the following,

1. Country SurfaceArea between 3,000,000 and 40,000,000 (Using the between operator)
2. The length of the City.District field is greater than 4
3. Create the calculated field 'CityPopulationPercentageOFCountryPopulation' that calculates what the field suggests"

This is what the City Table is described as:

> ID, name, Country, District, Population

This is what the Country Table is described as:

> Code, Name, Continent, Region, SurfaceArea, IndepYear, Population,
>   LifeExpectancy, GNP, LocalName, GovernmentForm, HeadOfState, Capital,
>   Code2

I have tried this and other variations with no luck:

```
Select City.ID, City.Name, City.Country, City.Population, Country.LifeExpectancy, Country.Name, Country.SurfaceArea, Country.GNP, 
(Select City.Population / Country.Population * 100, Count(City.Population / Country.population *100) AS "CityPopulationPercentageofCountryPopulation")
From City, Country
Where Country.SurfaceArea BETWEEN 3000000 and 40000000;
```

Like I said I am new at this and trying my best to figure it out by looking online etc.  Some help and maybe and explanation of how you figure it out would really help

Regards,

Comment: is this home work ? instructor have given this to you so you should try it yourself. or how you will learn ?

Comment: @echo_Samir this is a question on the homework yes.  I have looked in the book but he does not go by the book that we were required to order for the class. I have spent a total of about 3 hours looking at different webpages and books to try different things but have had no luck and that's why I have come here.  Maybe a direction would be helpful. Thanks regards

Comment: You need to join the tables properly, so that each city has its specific country data.

Comment: You also do not need the subquery, or the count - what you have as the first field in the subquery is fine on it's own once the tables are joined.  The `WHERE` is fine for the first restriction, but you need to add the length of city district restriction to it using `AND`.

Comment: @Orbling Thanks for the direction I will make some changes to the query however it may take me awhile. I will post my changes here once I have made them and tested them out for awhile.  Regards

Comment: @Orbling Thanks for your direction again and I think I have found what I need however I am unable to change the name to the column in the subquery. Could you please lead me in the right direction on how to change name Select City.ID, City.Name, City.Country, City.Population, Country.LifeExpectancy, Country.SurfaceArea, Country.Name, Country.GNP, (Select (City.Population) / Country.Population * 100 AS CityPopulationPercentageOfCountryPopulation)
From City INNER JOIN Country ON City.Country=Country.Code
Where Country.SurfaceArea BETWEEN 3000000 and 40000000 and LENGTH(City.District)>4 
limit 10;

Comment: @Orbling I found out how to change the column name. I had to write it like this (Select City.Population / Country.Population * 100) AS CityPopulationPercentageOfCountryPopulation.  That changed the Column name.  Thanks for your help regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select City.ID, City.Name, City.Country, City.Population, Country.LifeExpectancy, Country.SurfaceArea, Country.Name, Country.GNP, (Select City.Population / Country.Population * 100) AS CityPopulationPercentageOfCountryPopulation
From City INNER JOIN Country ON City.Country=Country.Code
Where Country.SurfaceArea BETWEEN 3000000 and 40000000 and LENGTH(City.District)>4 
limit 200;

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd get the city-to-country percentage, by country. I'm OK with telling you this because you were very close with the query you published above.

```
SELECT
  City.Country,
  SUM(City.Population) / Country.Population * 100 AS CityPopulationPercentageOFCountryPopulation
FROM City
INNER JOIN Country ON City.Country = Country.Code
GROUP BY City.Country
```

Has your instructor covered *inline views*, where a subquery is used like a table? I hope so, because that's how you'd include the calculated column with each city. Here's a simplified version with City ID, City Name, City Population, Country Code, and City Population percent:

```
SELECT
  City.ID,
  City.Name,
  City.Country,
  City.Population,
  PopPercent.CityPopulationPercentageOFCountryPopulation
FROM City
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      City.Country,
      SUM(City.Population) / Country.Population * 100 AS CityPopulationPercentageOFCountryPopulation
    FROM City
    INNER JOIN Country ON City.Country = Country.Code
    GROUP BY City.Country
) PopPercent ON City.Country = PopPercent.Country
```

You can take the query above and add another join to `Country` to get the country values, and then you should have all the information you need to filter by surface area as well as the length of the city district name. I'll leave that part to you :)

A final note: I don't have MySQL available this afternoon so this is from memory, untested. I apologize if there are any errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for the examples above and they are very useful but I do not think my instructor expects something that complicated; complicated for me.  My instructor did touch up on Sub queries but not like you have used it.  Is there maybe a simpler way of completing this question? Maybe something that advanced PPL such as yourself would not use? Thanks again for your response and I have been reviewing it for awhile now changing up my query.  Also I see you used an INNER Join Why not a Left join? Just curious and for understanding purposes only.  Regards

Comment: your example was extremely helpful and I posted what I think is what my instructor is looking for.  Thank you for your help because without it I could not have gotten this far. With that said if you look at my query in OBLINGs comments I am unable to change the name to the Subquery Column.  Could you review and let me know what I am doing incorrect or lead me in the right direction.  Thank you again Regards,

Comment: I was able to figure out how to change the Column name. I posted it under Orbling's comments.  Thanks for your help I appreciate it and if you have anything to add please let me know regards,

Comment: I'm glad this worked out for you, and yes - the correlated subquery (a subquery acting like a column) is a valid solution if you haven't covered inline views (a subquery acting like a table). Just note that in situations like yours, where all the rows in the `Country` table are used, the inline view will be much faster. You'll get to that soon enough :) Finally, I'm sorry I wasn't available to answer your followup questions - the first came shortly after I'd wrapped up for the day and started a busy evening. Good luck in your studies!